# RxJava in Liberty Profile: is it supported

Tags: rx-java, websphere-liberty

I am trying to build an EJB application from ground up. that has a lot of Async calls. RxJava seems to be a good choice as it as good semantics about the error conditions and time-outs (hopefully)

is there a sample app out there that uses RxJava within EJB app deployed to WebSphere-Liberty, please share

-thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently published a sample showing the two working together: 
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/introduction-to-using-rxjava-with-websphere-liberty/

Comment: Thank you a lot.  `This article demonstrates how to use some of the features from the RxJava library with WebSphere Liberty, while taking advantage of Java EE 7 Concurrent APIs, WebSockets, and Java SE 8 lambdas!`   is very helpful start, I will investigate it.  the only question is ** EJB Specs say not to create and manage your own threads**, but using the RxJava go against it? will RxJava create and manage threads implicitly?

Comment: will RxJava capture time-outs, can I specify the TimeOut when delegating work

Comment: @vamsi-vegi EJBs should not create their own threads, but EJBs are allowed to use JSR 236 ManagedScheduledExecutor, which is an API for an application to ask the container to manage threads, so you should be fine if you follow the sample.